# WinJs textarea focus issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, winjs

When running http://ichord.github.io/At.js/ page in IE10, it works correctly in a sense it returns focus to textarea after selecting suggestion from autocomplete list. It also works when I use on screen keyboard and touch input (on surface rt or simulator).

When I try to run the same code as WinJs app, it works for mouse/keyboard selection, but when I select item using touch it doesn't return focus to textarea, which is really frustrating. 
Is it known bug? Are there any known workarounds to it?
What it interesting it also doesn't hide on screen keyboard.

Comment: I believe this is in fact a bug; I've been having similar issues myself with the `win-hidefocus` class used for html5 textareas and whatnot.